# insert Btree with parents pointers

Tags: java, insert, b-tree

I tried writing an insert code in Java for Btree but cant split the nodes correctly, can anybody direct me to a good algorithm for insert,split and nonfullInset in Btrees?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming per node:

- maximum number of children for is D,
- maximum number of keys is K= D-1,
- minimum number of children is d = D/2,
- minimum number of keys is k= D/2-1

here are the algorithms:

- **Insert**: Search the tree to find the leaf node for containing the key. Insert the key. See if the key is over flown (the number of keys is higher than D-1), if not operation is complete. If over flown, **Split** the node into 2 nodes (itself and a new one), move the last (k) keys to the new node, leaving the node (leaf node) with k +1 keys. Move the last key in leaf node to parent. If parent is over flown repeat these steps.
- **Delete**: Search the tree to find the node containing the key you want to remove. 2 cases are possible. The container node is a leaf node or it is an internal non-leaf node. If it is an internal node, first find the immediate predecessor of the key in the node , which always comes from a lead node. Then replace the key with this predecessor key. Now you need to delete the key from a leaf node. (notice that the deletion from an internal node is always reduced to deletion from a leaf node). If a leaf node, remove the key from the leaf node. Check if the leaf node is under flown (has less than k keys), if not operation is complete. If under flown, however 3 cases are possible. If the node has a left sibling that has at least k+1 keys, then perform a right rotation via parent. Else if the node has a right sibling that has at least k+1 keys, then perform a left rotation via parent. Else if the node does not have any sibling with at least k+1 keys, then join the node with one of its sibling, while bringing down a key from parent. Then check if parent is under flown, if under flown repeat these steps to fix the parent.
- **Search**: is similar to binary search tree, the main difference is that now you need to also perform a search with in each node, since each node has sorted keys, you can perform a binary search over each node.